# SSH as user but I am root

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to ssh into an Ubuntu 20.04 VM as `user`.
However, after accessing the machine, if I run `whoami` I get `root`. If I try `su user` and provide the password I'm still `root`.

```
sig$ ssh user@10.0.7.444
user@10.0.7.444's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue Sep 22 09:47:13 CEST 2020

  System load:  0.96               Processes:                144
  Usage of /:   27.7% of 23.99GB   Users logged in:          0
  Memory usage: 19%                IPv4 address for docker0: 172.18.0.1
  Swap usage:   0%                 IPv4 address for eth0:    10.0.7.444

 * Kubernetes 1.19 is out! Get it in one command with:

     sudo snap install microk8s --channel=1.19 --classic

   https://microk8s.io/ has docs and details.

0 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.


Last login: Tue Sep 22 09:43:13 2020 from 194.161.123.245
-bash-5.0$ who -H
NAME     LINE         TIME             COMMENT
user     pts/0        2020-09-22 09:47 (194.161.123.245)
-bash-5.0$ users
user
-bash-5.0$ whoami
root
-bash-5.0$ passwd user
Changing password for user.
Current password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
-bash-5.0$ su user
Password:
bash-5.0$ whoami
root
```

What am I missing here? Why am I not `user`?

- UPDATE -

Below the `ids`:

```
-bash-5.0$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) euid=0(root) groups=1000(user),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lxd),998(docker)
-bash-5.0$ id user
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lxd),998(docker)
-bash-5.0$ id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: Without `-p` [`bash` drops privileges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391319/108618). Can you tell why your shell behaves like `bash -p`?